# I can't edit a shared Numbers spreadsheet

Tags: mac-appstore, numbers

I can't edit a shared spreadsheet in Numbers and an alert pops up to say a new update available.

So one would think I need to update Numbers, right?

But no, I have the most current update, so after the app directs me to the App Store to update, my only option is to open the app again.

I have restarted the app, and also restarted the computer, but still get the same thing.

AAAARGH!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error message you get?

Comment: Please also add information on the version of Numbers you have installed and the version of macOS you are using.

Comment: The message just says new Numbers update available and I then can't edit.( I can't see where to add screenshot)  I am running Numbers version 11.1.  on OSX 10.15.6. I don't want to update to OSX 11 as I spent a lot of money at the time for CS6 and it won't run on Big Sur

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I think sharing is the key problem.

I could edit the sheet ok on icloud—but it was a bit glitchy.

I was able to get it to run in Numbers by opening it in icloud and unsharing it. I know that solution wont work for most people, but I was able to work with it.